# pass arguments from docker run to dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Below one is my docker build command

```
docker build -t test/magento2:1.0.0 --build-arg BASE_URL=http://www.hostname.net/ --build-arg DATABASE_HOST=localhost --build-arg DATABASE_NAME=magento --build-arg DATABASE_USER=root --build-arg DATABASE_PASSWORD=root --build-arg ADMIN_USERNAME=test --build-arg ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=test --build-arg ADMIN_LASTNAME=Mobi --build-arg ADMIN_EMAIL=support@test.mobi --build-arg ADMIN_PASSWORD=test@123 --build-arg DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=en_US --build-arg DEFAULT_CURRENCY=INR --build-arg DEFAULT_TIMEZONE=Asia/Kolkata --build-arg BACKEND_FRONTNAME=admin .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG BASE_URL
ARG DATABASE_HOST
ARG DATABASE_NAME
ARG DATABASE_USER
ARG DATABASE_PASSWORD
ARG ADMIN_USERNAME
ARG ADMIN_FIRSTNAME
ARG ADMIN_LASTNAME
ARG ADMIN_EMAIL
ARG ADMIN_PASSWORD
ARG DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
ARG DEFAULT_CURRENCY
ARG DEFAULT_TIMEZONE
ARG BACKEND_FRONTNAME

RUN service mysql start && \
    cd /var/www/html && php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=$BASE_URL --db-host=$DATABASE_HOST --db-name=$DATABASE_NAME --db-user=$DATABASE_USER --db-password=$DATABASE_PASSWORD --admin-firstname=$ADMIN_FIRSTNAME --admin-lastname=$ADMIN_LASTNAME --admin-email=$ADMIN_EMAIL --admin-user=$ADMIN_USERNAME --admin-password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD --language=$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE --currency=$DEFAULT_CURRENCY --timezone=$DEFAULT_TIMEZONE --use-rewrites=1 --backend-frontname=$BACKEND_FRONTNAME
```

It is working fine, but I'm looking something

```
docker run <here I need to pass my arguments>
```

I'm thinking about **ENV** but it makes confusion. I don't know how to pass env variable from docker run command to dockerfile.

I believe there is a way to done.

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: maybe using `ARG` in docker file?

Comment: How did you solve this problem. I am on something similar on docker magento2 container

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung up to my mind, I added entrypoint, which executes shell script while docker run, that shell script check whether the magento is installed or not. If not install, it installs. If install, it ignores.

Comment: what about the paramters to pass with run with -e from where are you passing that

Comment: e.g) docker run -e a=b.... use this environment value in entrypoint shell script to install magento

Comment: how will verbose that what is happening as you wont see anything while running as in case of docker build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass argument to

`docker run`

so, when you run a container

just check

`docker run --help`

and you will get, among other things

`-e, --env value                   Set environment variables (default [])
      --env-file value              Read in a file of environment variables (default [])`

`ENV` is taken care of at build time

if you want

"I don't know how to pass env variable from docker run command to dockerfile"

you can't, `docker run` starts a container from a created image, a Dockerfile helps you build a new image

The flow

A Dockerfile -> `docker build -t myuser/myimage:v12.3 .` my new image

launch a container `docker run myuser/myimage:v12.3 myoptions` from my image myuser/myimage:v12.3

Comment: thanks! I need to run above `dockerfile RUN` while create container. what options I need to use? is CMD suite?

Comment: Check `docker run --env`

Comment: I know buddy `docker run -e` command. When I run this I need to install magento as per env variable. My doubt is where I need to write this logic to install magento in dockerfile.

This is I'm looking exactly, in below link he target the shell script to install magento
https://github.com/alankent/docker-magento2-demo-apache/blob/master/Dockerfile#L33

docker run commands seems `docker run -e PUBLIC_HOST=yourhost.example.com .....` 
As per my understanding dockerfile RUN does't execute while `docker run`, then how he execute shell script while `docker run`.

Comment: notice at the end of your link `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c"]
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/runserver"]` the CMD and ENTRYPOINT are starting the process in the image

Comment: Your Dockerfile lacks a CMD or ENTRYPOINT, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile